# How to properly convert my .Net Core project to .Net Framework and mitigate package incompatibilities?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, .net-core, .net-4.0

I have a webservice project that I started building in .net Core 3.1, but it turns out that it needed to be built in .Net Framework.

I changed it as shown in a few SO posts, as such:

```
 <TargetFramework>net461</TargetFramework>
```

But when I build the project, I get this error

```
Error   NU1202  Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory 5.0.9 is not compatible with net48 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.8) / win7-x64. Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory 5.0.9 supports: netstandard2.1 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.1)    FinscanPremiumAPI
```

I removed that dependency to see what would happen and then most of the method calls in my `Startup.cs` showed as errors, each with this description:

```
Error   CS1061  'IApplicationBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'UseAuthorization' and no accessible extension method 'UseAuthorization' accepting a first argument of type 'IApplicationBuilder' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  FinscanPremiumAPI
```

I started a .Net Framework API project from scratch to see what dependencies that used, and saw that the project structure differs quite a bit from more .Net Core one, including no `Startup.cs` file.

So is there a way around this that does not involve me setting up a new environment from scratch before importing all my logic over? I'm actually confused as to how just simply changing the target framework did work for other people, when the project structures and dependency requirements seem to differ so much.

Thank!

Comment: May I ask why you want to go to .NET Framework? That's deprecated now, and the way to go forward is .NET 5.0 or .NET6.0. Particularly because you were at .NET Core 3.1 already.

Comment: I'm going to have to merge my code into an existing project thats .Net Framework based.  I could try convince them to upgrade though.

Comment: Or, if your project is a library, you could change it to NetStandard. That is compatible to both worlds.